# Python: Last index is not being iterated

Tags: python, list, function, loops, iteration

I am working on a problem where I where I am given a list of duplicate numbers and I have to return a new list of all unique values from the initial list.

Here is my solution:

```
new_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5]
updated_lst = []
for i in range(0,len(new_list)-1):
    if new_list[i] != new_list[i+1]:
        updated_lst.append(new_list[i])
print(updated_lst)
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4] but its missing the 5 from the new_list.

Also, I am new to python and know that know that I can do something like

```
updated_list = []
for i in new_list:
   if i not in updated_list[]:
       updated_list.append(i)
```

But I was wondering how can I make my initial solution work.

Thank you very much

Comment: I would just add a check after the for-loop if the last item is not equal to second-to-last one and append it if so. The last item is just a special case which can't be handled like the rest.

Comment: Is your list guaranteed to be in order, when you get it? Because your algorithm won't work correctly if the numbers are out of order (consider `[1, 2, 1]`). For the algorithm you're using, you should *always* include the last item in the input list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp):  for this issue, but in your specific case here is how I would do it:

```
new_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5]
new_list = list(dict.fromkeys(new_list))
print(new_list)
```

ouput: "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"

hope this helped

Comment: I think that set() instead of disct would be more appropriate in this case

Comment: Yea True but either way it answers the question and takes up less lines of code then attempted code.

Comment: @Edo98 note, `list(set(new_list))` doesn't maintain order

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the `range(N, M)` built-in function will iterate from N to M - 1, so you should not set your second argument to `len(new_list)-1` but to `len(new_list)`.

See the reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

This won't make your first solution work but explains why you don't get your last item.

Stated this solution is not optimal, the way to achieve it by manually looking at indices would be:

```py
new_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5]
updated_lst = []

for i in range(0,len(new_list)):
    found = False

    for j in range(0, len(updated_lst)):
        if new_list[i] == updated_lst[j]:
            found = True
            break

    if not found:
        updated_lst.append(new_list[i])

print(updated_lst)
```

This is all good for learning but I'd refrain from using this outside of a playground as it's unnecessarily complex and inelegant.

Thanks @ncasale for helping improving the answer.

As a side note, your first algorithm will not remove duplicates but only repetitions. Another way to achieve what you want could be `list(set(new_list))`.

Comment: Iterating to `len(new_list)` will throw an exception when `if new_list[i] != new_list[i+1]:` is called.

Comment: Indeed, but that's a wrong algorithm, doesn't remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your problem requires you to iterate through the list, but you can easily find all of the unique elements in a list by casting it as a `set`. You can then get a `list` back by casting that `set` back to a `list`.

```py
new_list = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5]
unique = set(new_list)
print(list(unique))
```

Returns:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: The order of printed list isn't guaranteed. If important the "list" should be replaced by "sorted".

Comment: Agreed. The asker didn't specify order but if order is required then `sorted` can certainly be used.

Comment: Well, `sorted` isn't exactly correct, because `sorted` will return *a sorted list* not a list with the items in the original order, which is lost by using set. In modern python, dict objects are guaranteed to maintain order, so, `list(dict.fromkeys(new_list))` works if you want something cute.

Answer (score 0):

**Set** is an unordered collection data type that has **no duplicate elements**.
For the desired output, we can convert the given list into a set, which will remove all the duplicate elements. Then we can again convert it into a list. As follows:

```
new_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,5]
x=set(new_list)
print(list(x))
```

This will print the output as:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This way we get the list without any duplicate elements.
Hope it helps!